# Why is 看 all the way in the back in 有好戏看了?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I saw this sentence and was wondering why 看 is placed behind everything in 有好戏看了? Is it supposed to be verb linking as in "Have drama and watch"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the only logical location for "看" to be placed:

有(have)好戏(good show)看(to watch)了(语气词/modal particle). I think the sentence should end with an "exclamation mark" rather than the "question mark" shown.